# Add sound effect when a button is pressed

Tags: java, swing, desktop-application, javasound

I have created a simple desktop application (MCQ simulator) in Java Swing.
Now I want a simple sound to be generated (may be MP3 file residing on disk) when user presses a button (continue or submit button).

What are the suitable built-in class/methods for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Java Sound](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) provides support for sound in Java apps.  Note there is no SPI for MP3 by default, but one can be added easily.  See the linked page for details.

For a much simpler sound, look to [`Toolkit.beep()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#beep%28%29).